# How can add a word into a specific position into a string in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a variable that has a hardcoded value,

> customers.name = 'Schmidt'

```
declare @value as nvarchar(max)
set @value = 'customers.name = ''Schmidt'''
```

that I would like to change @value in this way

> customers.last_name = 'Schmidt'

how this can be done using query?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `REPLACE(@value,'.name', 'last_name')`? This question i way too unclear.

Comment: `REPLACE(@value,'name', 'last_name')` could work thanks :)

Comment: How could I make it more specific, please?

Comment: Comments pointed to `REPLACE` already. Taking the title literally, you might read about `STUFF` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `customers.name` for `customers.last_name`.

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(200) = 'customers.name = ''Schmidt'''

SELECT
    OriginalText = @text,
    ReplacedText = REPLACE(@text, 'customers.name', 'customers.last_name')

/*
Result:
    OriginalText: customers.name = 'Schmidt'    
    ReplacedText: customers.last_name = 'Schmidt'
*/
```

In general basis, when replacing strings, the bigger they are the lower the chance of replacing by mistake. If you are sure that the value will always start with `customers.name =` then you should replace that with `customers.last_name =`. If you try to replace simply `name` you might end up replacing it on another occurence of the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'customers.name = ''Schmidt'''
      ,@Replacement AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'last_name'
      ,@SearchString AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'name'

SET @Value = REPLACE(@value, @SearchString, @Replacement)

PRINT @Value;
```